# Question regarding the Jordan basis of $A$ when $A$ has simple eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

Let $A$ be a real $n \times n$ matrix with real eigenvalues, and let $PJP^{-1}=A$ be the Jordan decomposition. I'm interested what the columns of $P$ and $P^{-1}$ are when their associated eigenvalues have multiplicity one.

Suppose the eigenvalue $\lambda_i \in \sigma(A)$ has multiplicity 1. My intuition tells me that the $i$th row of $P$ is an eigenvector of $A$ associated with $\lambda_i$, and the $i$th row of $P^{-1}$ is an eigenvector of $A^T$ (i.e. the right eigenvector of $A$) associated with $\lambda_i$. Is this true? If not, then what exactly are these twos supposed to be? I would appreciate any sources that go into detail on the properties of the columns of $P$ and $P^{-1}$.

Comment: They don't have to be unit vectors at all. It is more likely that you will find a counterexample, than not.

Comment: For example, $\begin{bmatrix}52&-30\\75&-43\end{bmatrix}.$

Comment: @Invisible good catch, I’ll remove the unit part. Still curious if this left/right eigenvector part is true though.

Comment: Write $JP^{-1}=P^{-1}A$ and left multiply by $\mathbf e_r$, the $r$th standard basis vector for appropriate $r$.  What do you conclude?

Comment: That the rth row of P inverse is a left eigenvector of A. :) Very neat, thanks